# Why can't I loop over a Stack using a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, stack

I have a Stack with 3 items and I want to loop over each item. If I do this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();
        s.add(1);
        s.add(2);
        s.add(3);
    
        for (Integer num = s.pop(); !s.isEmpty(); num = s.pop()) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
}
```

then it only prints out 3 and 2 but not 1. Why is that?

Comment: After last pop it's empty and doesn't iterate over that value.

Comment: When you pop the last number, `s.isEmpty()` becomes true, so the for-loop finishes without printing the last number.

Comment: @K.Nicholas @khelwood So a for loop executes the third statement (`num = s.pop()` in this case) and then checks the condition (`!s.isEmpty()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop pops the stack then exits the loop if the stack is empty.

```
for (Integer num = s.pop(); !s.isEmpty(); num = s.pop()) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Put another way, `num = s.pop()` is run before the test `!s.isEmpty()`. So on the final iteration, the stack is empty, therefore the loop body isn't executed.

There are many different ways around this. One thing you could do is use a `while` loop instead:

```
while (!s.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```

Comment: So the order in which a for loop executes its statements is: 1st statement at the start, runs, then loops executing the 3rd statement, checking condition, and running?

Comment: @DVT you are correct. There are some neat flow charts out there which explain it a bit better, e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-for-loop-with-examples/

Answer (score 1):

For loop consists of 3 expressions: *initialization, termination, increment*:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    //
}
```

1. *initialization* is executed only once
2. *termination* is executed each iteration
3. *increment* is executed each iteration

In your case you retrieve from the stack **twice** on the first iteration, hence your problem with a non-printing element.
You might be wondering why does it print `3,2` and not `2,1`? That's because *increment* expression is invoked **after** (in the very end) each iteration through the loop.

All of sections are optional, so you can iterate this way:

```
for (; ; ) {
    System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```

... and you will eventually have `java.util.EmptyStackException` on an attempt to pop an element from already empty stack.

So the most basic way to iterate over a stack with a for loop is to make use of *termination* statement as a "safe-check":

```
for (; !s.isEmpty(); ) {
    System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```

... which is basically a more complex and counterintuitive way to write a `while`-loop:

```
while (!s.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```

Docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Nice answer! "less counterintuitive" = "more intuitive"?

Comment: my point is that for loop w/ the single termination section is LESS intuitive way to just write a while loop=)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the stack is already empty, when the condition is evaluated.

Few options(not all) how to correctly pop and print all items:

1. Do-while loop. As mentioned in comments, will throw `EmptyStackException`, if the stack is initially empty.

```
do {
  System.out.println(s.pop());
} while (!s.empty());
```

2. While loop.

```
while (!s.empty()) {
  System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```

Comment: Note: the do-while loop will work in this scenario, but would result in an `EmptyStackException` if the stack is empty to begin with.